# How to write file handling operations in class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase, httppostedfile

UI

```
<input type = "file" title="Please upload some file" name="file" />
```

MVC

```
/*below method is called from a MVC controller 
 this method resides for now in MVC project itself*/
public IEnumerable<CustomerTO> FetchJson(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FileName))
        {
            {
                file.saveAs("details.txt");
                string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                IEnumerable<CustomerTO> customers=
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerTO>>(json);
               return customers; 
            }
        }
    }
```

When the above method in MVC project or some kind of web based project, all references are find fine.

But I am thinking to create a utility class to handle all such operations.
So I created a class library project & added a class Utitlity.cs

Class Library

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerTO> FetchJson(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        //but HttpPostedFile is throwing error.
        //NOTE Ideally,I shouldn't be saving the posted file
    }
```

Now I know FileUpload is UI control HttpPostedFile handles all operations related to this.

I can easily add reference `using System.Web` but I doubt if that's right??

But how do I address my requirement then without any kind of overhead??
*Memory allocation, execution & all such is very critical*

Comment: Not quite sure how you can claim the first works - your file input does not have a `name` attribute so the parameter will be `null`. And how are you calling the 2nd 'utility' method - you still need an action method in your `Controller` to receive the request.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry!! added the missing details

Comment: It would need to be `name="file"` to bind to a parameter `HttpPostedFile file` :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, that also corrected. Thanks  :)

Comment: You still need to controller method, but inside it you can just call `return yourUtilityAssemby.FetchJson(file);` but I suggest you rename one or the other to avoid confusion (and allow you to include a `using` statement in the controller

Answer (score 1):

Read this answer once you make sure that controller method receives posted file reference properly.

You don't need to add `System.Web` reference in class library. Instead just pass file contents to refactored method. Moreover since you are making a utility class, make sure it can return any type of DTO and not just `CustomerDTO`. You should be able to use the same class/ method, if you ever need to pass in Accounts file and get `AccountDTO`s out of it, for example.

In fact, you should be able to use that code for deserializing any string content to any type you want. You could use `Generics` here.

```
// Controller.cs
public IEnumerable<CustomerTO> FetchJson(HttpPostedFile file) 
{
    string fileContent;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FileName)) {
        file.saveAs("details.txt");
        fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var customers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CustomerTO>>(content); // Refactored

    return customers; 
}

// JsonSerializer.cs
public static T Deserialize<T>(string content) {
    // ...
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
}
```

Reading file content using `StreamReader` in Controller need not be refactored. That's unnecessary IMO.

Comment: Great. But as I mentioned saving file is overhead to me

Comment: Sure. User uploads file, need to read the content, Deserialize & do some operation( ex return to UI) That's it. If user uploads hundreds of files saving that many files isn't overhead

Comment: If you don't want copy of uploaded file then don't save it. Instead use `file.InputStream`. Also you did not talk about possibility of multiple file uploads in you question. Make sure you clearly indicate actual scenario in question.